# Install CentOS 6.7 guest without internet connection via console?

Tags: installation, centos-6, kvm-switch

I have problems installing a kvm guest CentOS over ssh on a server without internet.

This is what I do:

```
fallocate -l 200G /var/lib/libvirt/images/dbpvvtlzg.img

virt-install \
 --accelerate \
 --os-variant=rhel6 \
 --name=dbpvvtlzg \
 --cpu host \
 --vcpus=4 \
 --ram=16384 \
 --network bridge=br0 \
 --mac=RANDOM \
 --connect qemu:///system \
 -f /var/lib/libvirt/images/dbpvvtlzg.img \
 --cdrom /var/local/repo/CentOS/6/isos/x86_64/CentOS-6.7-x86_64-LiveDVD.iso
```

It works fine until I get to the bootscreen of the LiveDVD. I am able to select the `textinstall0` from the boot options, I see the first hint of linux starting, and then it just hangs in an empty screen with only one character: `�`

Any hints? More info can be provided

Answer (score 0):

`--extra-args "console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial"`
did the trick